# Adding New Column to Select-Object -ExpandProperty

Tags: powershell

I'm working with Azure AD and I'm getting the list of services and their status for a specific license but I'm having trouble trying to get the desired output.

The basic command I'm using is this:

```
((Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses).Where{ $_.AccountSkuId -like $SkuId } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServiceStatus
```

That produces output similar to this

```
ServicePlan           ProvisioningStatus
-----------           ------------------
TEAMS1                Disabled
PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT Disabled
SWAY                  Disabled
INTUNE_O365           PendingActivation
YAMMER_ENTERPRISE     Disabled
RMS_S_ENTERPRISE      Disabled
OFFICESUBSCRIPTION    Success
MCOSTANDARD           Disabled
SHAREPOINTWAC         Success
SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE  Success
EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE Success
```

This is all fine when only one user is passed into the function this code is in but when more users are passed in rather and printing a distinct set of output for each user it just prints all the items again (minus the heading) in one giant list.

Ideally I'm looking to add another column to the output, but I'm not having much success with it. I've tried using some calculated properties such as:

```
 ((Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses).Where{ $_.AccountSkuId -like $SkuId } | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$UPN}},@{n='ServicePlan';e={$_.ServiceStatus.ServicePlan.ServiceName}},@{n='ProvisioningStatus';e={$_.ServiceStatus.ProvisioningStatus}}
```

This kind of worked but rather than get a nice table with an added column that had the UPN it rolled the Name, ServicePlan and Provisioning into a object with those values as NoteProperties and when it's displayed it looks like this

```
Name             ServicePlan                                           ProvisioningStatus
----             -----------                                           ------------------
user1@domain.com {TEAMS1, PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT, SWAY, INTUNE_O365...} {Disabled, Disabled, Disabled, PendingActivation...}
user2@domain.com {TEAMS1, PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT, SWAY, INTUNE_O365...} {PendingProvisioning, Disabled, Disabled, PendingActivation...}
```

That could be useful but I'm kind of lost at this point of how I could possibly get this information to look something like this

```
Name  ServicePlan           ProvisioningStatus
----  -----------           ------------------
user1 TEAMS1                Disabled
user1 PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT Disabled
user1 SWAY                  Disabled
user1 ........................................

user2 TEAMS1                Disabled
user2 PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT Disabled
user2 SWAY                  Disabled
user2 ........................................
```

Or alternatively like

```
user1
ServicePlan           ProvisioningStatus
-----------           ------------------
TEAMS1                Disabled
PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT Disabled
SWAY                  Disabled
........................................

user2
ServicePlan           ProvisioningStatus
-----------           ------------------
TEAMS1                Disabled
PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT Disabled
SWAY                  Disabled
........................................
```

Thanks for reading my long question and any responses.

Comment: `| Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$UPN}} -ExpandProperty ServiceStatus | Format-Table ServicePlan, ProvisioningStatus -GroupBy Name`

Comment: With a slight change this worked.  I used `Format-Table -GroupBy Name`  Thanks for the help